# A gap in a proof of Pappus's theorem.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

For reference, I'll use the labels in the picture from  [Wolfram Mathworld's entry](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PappussHexagonTheorem.html).

[image: labels]

In the proof of Pappus's Theorem in the Euclidean plane from Menelaus's Theorem, the triangle formed from the lines $AF$, $BD$, and $CE$ is used. Thus the proof may fail if the sets of lines $\left \{ AF, BD, CE \right \}$ and $\left \{ FB, DC, EA \right \}$ are concurrent. Is there a guarantee that one of the sets above is non-concurrent or that a theorem similar to Menelaus's that works on concurrent lines can be substituted?

Comment: Assuming all points are distinct and $B$ is between $A$ and $C$, and $E$ is between $D$ and $F$, then it follows that for example $BF \cap CD$ is inside $\triangle AFC$ while $AE \cap CD$ is outside it, so the lines $\{FB,DC,EA\}$ cannot be concurrent. The details of a formal proof depend on what axioms you work with.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot assume any particular betweenness on the sets $\left \{ A,B,C \right \}$ or $\left \{ D,E,F \right \}$.

Comment: You can always assume that one of the points is between the other two on each line, then relabel as necessary use the same argument.

Comment: I can do it for one of the sets, but not both. If I fix one set's betweenness, then changing the other set's order is consequential to that type of argument. For example, the middle point may or may not be joined to the middle point on the other line, depending on whether you swap $B$ and $C$.

Comment: There are two sets of lines, and the same argument as above will still apply to one of them. For example, if in the posted figure $D$ were between $E$ and $F$ instead, consider the other $3$ lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a partial answer, since it doesn't exactly stay in the Euclidean plane, but it probably can be adapted to a fully Euclidean proof. As it is, this is acceptable for my purposes.

Adjoin a line at infinity to the Euclidean plane to get the real projective plane, and then use a collineation to send the line $DE$ to infinity. Stepping back into Euclidean terms,  we get the following:

- Three distinct but collinear points $A, B, C$.
- Three pairs of distinct lines $(a_{i},a_{o}),(b_{i},b_{o}),(c_{i},c_{o})$ passing through $A, B, C$ respectively such that the pairs $(a_{o},b_{i}),(b_{o},c_{i}),(c_{o},a_{i})$ are the only ones that are parallel.

We wish to show that at least one of the sets of lines $\left \{ a_{i},b_{i},c_{i} \right \}$ or $\left \{ a_{o},b_{o},c_{o} \right \}$ is non-concurrent.

Looking at directed line lengths on the line $AB$, we see that $AB + BC + CA = 0$.

Assume that both  $\left \{ a_{i},b_{i},c_{i} \right \}$ and $\left \{ a_{o},b_{o},c_{o} \right \}$ are concurrent. Using similar triangles and the fact that pairs of lines are parallel, the following chain of equalities must hold for some $k\in \mathbb{R}$.

$$k^{3}\ast AB = k^{2}\ast BC = k\ast CA = AB$$

Since the points $A, B, C$ are distinct, the only way the first equation can hold is if $k$ is a root of $x^{2} + x + 1$. This polynomial does not have any real roots, so our assumption has failed.